# MATLAB: copyobj with datetime plots

Tags: matlab, datetime, copy

I am trying to copy a plot using `copyobj`. I am having a difficult time to copy a plot once I incorporate `datetime`.

Here's my code:

```
data = randn([100,1]);
time = datetime(737126-99:737126, 'ConvertFrom', 'datenum', 'Format','defaultdate');

oldFig = figure;

hold on
barOriginal(1) = bar(data .* (data>=0), 'blue');
barOriginal(2) = bar(data .* (data<0), 'red');
hold off

oldFigTime = figure;

hold on
barOriginalTime(1) = bar(time, data .* (data>=0), 'blue');
barOriginalTime(2) = bar(time, data .* (data<0), 'red');
hold off

newFig = figure;

sub1 = subplot(2,1,1);
sub2 = subplot(2,1,2);
copyobj(barOriginal, sub1)          % working
copyobj(barOriginalTime, sub2)      % failing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this does not work for you please comment, yet it does work for the given example if it is ok to keep `time` as datenum:

```
data = randn([100,1]);
%time = datetime(737126-99:737126, 'ConvertFrom', 'datenum', 'Format','defaultdate');
time = 737126-99:737126; %just as number


oldFig = figure;

hold on
barOriginal(1) = bar(data .* (data>=0), 'blue');
barOriginal(2) = bar(data .* (data<0), 'red');
hold off

oldFigTime = figure;

hold on
barOriginalTime(1) = bar(time, data .* (data>=0), 'blue');
barOriginalTime(2) = bar(time, data .* (data<0), 'red');
datetick('x') %and now turn it into a Datetime
hold off

newFig = figure;

sub1 = subplot(2,1,1);
sub2 = subplot(2,1,2);
copyobj(barOriginal, sub1)          % working
copyobj(barOriginalTime, sub2)      % will be copied from as number
datetick('x')                       % and has to be converted too
```